# When should you validate a JWT token in a React App?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

I recently implemented JWT tokens in my React + ASP.NET Core 6 Web application.

When a user signs in, the request is sent via HTTP request to the server to issue a JWT token
back to the client. The client then sends another request to validate the JWT token received, in which the server sends a "success" or "rejected" response back to the client.

Now, this is done once when a user signs in, and the JWT token is stored in a Cookie. The Cookie expires 5 days after it is issued, so if a user closes the tab or browser, if they reopen the application, they will automatically be logged in due to the Cookie stored. Note: The JWT token from the Cookie is validated again once a user comes back.

Here is the tricky part...

Since this is a SPA, the JWT token validation happens on the useEffect() method in the AuthContext that handles User Auth.

When a user clicks into a new page, only the child components are rendered, and the AuthContext / Navbar are not, since they are Higher Order Components acting as wrappers. Because of this, the JWT token is not revalidated each time a user visits a new page.

**Is this secure? Should a revalidation trigger every single time a user visits a new "page"? Are there any security concerns?**